# pipenv создает глобальное окружение

Tags: python, pipenv

Столкнулся со странной проблемой. 
Имею на компьютере развернутый проект на питоне, при развертовании проекта установил виртуально окружение с помощью

```
pipenv --python 3.7.5
```

Окружение создалось. И я работал на проекте пол года. Сейчас понадобилось создать еще одно виртуалное окружение pipenv. Но при вызове

```
pipenv --python 3.7.6
```

затерается старое окружение. Получатеся что окружение работает как глобальное. Пытался создавать с переменной окружения как в документации PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=true новсё ровно создается глобально.

Comment: По моему, виртуальность работает через добавление в переменную окружения (PATH) на первое место путь до питона в виртуальном окружении, поэтому за раз только одно venv работает

Comment: У парня который со мной на проекте работает, создаются отдельные окружения если он из нужной директории вызывает
```pipenv --python 3.7.6```

Answer (score 1):

Долго бился не понимая в чем проблема. Оказалось что когда мне настраивали в прошлый раз окружение , его создали для домашней директории. И получается что pipenv не может создать виртуальное окружение внутри виртуального окружения. После удаления окружения домашней директори, и после удаления Pipfile из домашней директории, появилась возможность создавать виртуальные окружения для каждого проекта отдельно.